# jniLibs still not working after add folder jniLibs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, .so

I use library class that load ***libsomething.so***, also i make everything same as demo (package name).

1. Actually i'm edited demo project that seem build use old Android Studio (gradle 0.5+)

   [Image - Structure of my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAQ0q.png)
2. I'm follow instruction to add Directory "jniLibs" that have same place with /java/main but still reader.java got "Cannot resolve JNI Function"
3. I'm follow another instruction that set libs as jniLibs, but still reader.java got "Cannot resolve JNI Function".

   ```
   sourceSets {
   main {
       jni.srcDirs = []
       jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
   }
   ```

   }
4. i have created package name android.hardware.uhf.magic->reader.java
    [Image - class that provided in .so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCbe5.png)
5. The way i load library like `System.LoadLibrary("something")`

Is there any step that i have missed?

Thank You.

Comment: This is an old question, but it somehow passed under my radar. Two issues here: **1)** for a while, *armeabi* has been dropped from NDK and from gradle. You are expected to provide *armeabi-v7a* ***and*** *arm64-v8a* instead. **2)** Don't expect Java environment to resolve the native methods that you implement in prebuilt library. The inspection only uses the C++ sources if it can find them.

Answer (score 4):

What solved it for me was adding an `ndk` section under `android.defaultConfig` in my gradle config:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
+        ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any exact answer for your question.But I will try to give you an Answer.

Because I am Use **jniLibs** too.

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jni
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk file
    }
```

In Your code I think you Used only **"libs"**, is that your exact **jniLibs** path..? if not then give the full path. Also add this Line in your **gradle.properties**

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Hope this helps..(:

Comment: i've set Libs because "Libs" Directory inside App. I've just set Gradle as ur suggest but still don't work. I've also tried to set scrDir to 'App/Libs'.
Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no error 
here my code
 `try { Log.d("LOAD", "TestLibrary: "); System.loadLibrary("uhf-tools"); }catch (Exception e){  Log.d("ERROR", "TestLibrary: "+e.toString());  }`

i've just extracted my debug.apk to .zip. In there i find libs directory that contain libuhf-tools.so